# How do I search for a specific value in a string in a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pull data from this API: https://data.medicare.gov/resource/ax9d-vq6k.json

My front end has an input field where I want the users to be able to search for their zip code.

```
$('#searchClick').on("click", function() {

// collecting the value from the input field.
var zipCode = $('#zipCode').val().trim();

// This is our API call using the name from the input box to make the call for all surgeons with a last name of something specific. 
var queryURL = "https://data.medicare.gov/resource/ax9d-vq6k.json?human_address=" + zipCode;
console.log("Click Is Working");

// Clearing the main Div after every search
$(".resultsDiv").empty();




// This is the Actual API call.  
$.ajax({
    url: queryURL,
    method: "GET"
}).done(function(response) {
    // console.log(response);
```

The JSON object in my API call returns this:

```js
{
  "rn_staffing_rating": 4,
  "federal_provider_number": "015009",
  "health_inspection_rating": 5,
  "processing_date": "2017-12-01T00:00:00",
  "provider_state": "AL",
  "staffing_rating": 4,
  "qm_rating": 5,
  "location": {
    "latitude": "34.514971",
    "human_address": "{\"address\":\"701 MONROE STREET NW\",\"city\":\"RUSSELLVILLE\",\"state\":\"AL\",\"zip\":\"35653\"}",
    "needs_recoding": false,
    "longitude": "-87.736372"
  },
  "overall_rating": 5,
  "provider_name": "BURNS NURSING HOME, INC."
}
```

I just want to request where the `Human_address` contains the zip code that the user searches.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Parse `human_address` and compare against prop `zip`.

Comment: Have you tried using `result.location.human_address`? The `result` should already have been parsed when the `done()`-function is being called. And if `human_address` contains a JSON string (so `.zip` is not available as a property) then you should serously consider fixing that on the server side (if you control that part of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `zip` you want to find is stored within JSON data in the `location.human_address` property, so you'll need to parse that before comparing the values to the ZIP you want to find. You can use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to do that:

```js
var response = getData();
var zip = '35150';
var zipMatches = response.filter(function(o) {
  return JSON.parse(o.location.human_address).zip == zip;
});
console.log(zipMatches);


function getData() {
  // proxy for your AJAX call...
  return [{
    "rn_staffing_rating": 4,
    "federal_provider_number": "015009",
    "health_inspection_rating": 5,
    "processing_date": "2017-12-01T00:00:00",
    "provider_state": "AL",
    "staffing_rating": 4,
    "qm_rating": 5,
    "location": {
      "latitude": "34.514971",
      "human_address": "{\"address\":\"701 MONROE STREET NW\",\"city\":\"RUSSELLVILLE\",\"state\":\"AL\",\"zip\":\"35653\"}",
      "needs_recoding": false,
      "longitude": "-87.736372"
    },
    "overall_rating": 5,
    "provider_name": "BURNS NURSING HOME, INC."
  }, {
    "rn_staffing_rating": 5,
    "federal_provider_number": "015010",
    "health_inspection_rating": 2,
    "processing_date": "2017-12-01T00:00:00",
    "provider_state": "AL",
    "staffing_rating": 5,
    "qm_rating": 5,
    "location": {
      "latitude": "33.164666",
      "human_address": "{\"address\":\"315 WEST HICKORY STREET\",\"city\":\"SYLACAUGA\",\"state\":\"AL\",\"zip\":\"35150\"}",
      "needs_recoding": false,
      "longitude": "-86.254598"
    },
    "overall_rating": 4,
    "provider_name": "COOSA VALLEY NURSING FACILITY"
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the common way to do this is to just loop through the response array and find the matches:

for example :

```
var results = [{
    "rn_staffing_rating": 4,
    "federal_provider_number": "015009",
    "health_inspection_rating": 5,
    "processing_date": "2017-12-01T00:00:00",
    "provider_state": "AL",
    "staffing_rating": 4,
    "qm_rating": 5,
    "location": {
      "latitude": "34.514971",
      "human_address": "{\"address\":\"701 MONROE STREET NW\",\"city\":\"RUSSELLVILLE\",\"state\":\"AL\",\"zip\":\"35653\"}",
      "needs_recoding": false,
      "longitude": "-87.736372"
    },
    "overall_rating": 5,
    "provider_name": "BURNS NURSING HOME, INC."
  }, {
    "rn_staffing_rating": 5,
    "federal_provider_number": "015010",
    "health_inspection_rating": 2,
    "processing_date": "2017-12-01T00:00:00",
    "provider_state": "AL",
    "staffing_rating": 5,
    "qm_rating": 5,
    "location": {
      "latitude": "33.164666",
      "human_address": "{\"address\":\"315 WEST HICKORY STREET\",\"city\":\"SYLACAUGA\",\"state\":\"AL\",\"zip\":\"35150\"}",
      "needs_recoding": false,
      "longitude": "-86.254598"
    },
    "overall_rating": 4,
    "provider_name": "COOSA VALLEY NURSING FACILITY"
  }];
var new_result = [];
for (var i=0 ; i < result.length ; i++)
{
    if ( result[i]['location']['human_address'].hasOwnProperty('zip') && result[i]['location']['human_address']['zip'] == "value_to_be_searched") 
    {
        new_result.push(result[i]);
    }
}
console.log(new_result);
```